# Converting string into year-month in R?

Tags: r, date

I want to convert the following string into year-month?

```
df <- tribble(
  ~date, 
  '20201227', 
)
```

Here is the desired output.

```
new_df <- tribble(
  ~date, 
  '2020-12', 
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `Date` class and use `format`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
     mutate(date = format(as.Date(date, '%Y%m%d'), '%Y-%m'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option using `gsub` (but [the `as.Date` answer by @akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993250/12158757) is more recommended)

```
transform(
  df,
  date = gsub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2}).*", "\\1-\\2", date)
)
```

gives

```
     date
1 2020-12
```